# How can I restrict VS Code engine minimum version for my VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control, vscode-extensions

I am developing my VS Code extension. Old version is `1.0.0`. I add a new feature which leverages VS Code's new feature [`Remote-development`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_remote-development-preview), which only available with VS Code engine version higher than `1.36.1`. I added my extension new feature and upgraded my extension to `2.0.0`.

I would like to restrict user's VS Code engine when installing my extension. If user would like to install my extension v2.0.0, he must have VS Code engine version higher than `1.36.1`.

I set the minimum VS Code version restriction in extension's `package.json` file, `engines` fields, following [VS Code Official Docs: Extension Manifest](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest). But later I figured out that user with VS Code engine version lower then `1.36.1` still can search my `2.0.0` extension and install it. VS Code does not pop out any suggestion to inform user to upgrade their engine. And the extension can not work properly, of course.

```
// package.json
"engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.36.1"
  }
```

Did I miss something?
How can I restrict user with lower VS Code engine version either to upgrade their VS Code engine or install the old extension release?

Now user with lower VS Code engine version just install my new extension release and the extension can not work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In my experience, VSCode definitely respects the version in `engines` when it comes to updating extensions. Or what exactly do you mean by "search for 2.0.0"? Using the "Install Another Version..." UI to install that version specifically?

Comment: @Gama11 I mean when user with VS Code engine version lower then 1.36.1 tries to install my extension, VS Code will install the latest `2.0.0` extension instead of `1.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason myself:

1. VS Code `package.json`'s `engines` field does work. If user's engine lower than the required minimum engine version, VS Code will install lower version extension for user.
2. In my scenario, I have a dependency extension, whose engine requirement is not aligned with the main extension. This is the root cause of the main extension installation failure.
   When user with lower version VS Code engine tries to install my extension, VS Code checks the dependency extension's engine requirement and fails to find a main extension release with proper dependency release. In this case, the installation of main extension fails.

Solution:
I have to find a way to remove my previous extension release from marketplace, whose engine requirement is not right.